# StructureMap creating instance

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have the concrete types for interfaces configured at startup, but I want to create instances of the concrete type at runtime with setting properties or setting different values in the constructor.  All the creating of instances I see have the knowledge of what the concrete type is, at runtime I don't know the concrete type.  Is there a way to create a concrete instance of an interface/class without knowing the concrete type?  This is what I have seen:

```
[Test]
public void DeepInstanceTest_with_SmartInstance()
{
    assertThingMatches(registry =>
    {
        registry.ForRequestedType<Thing>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<Thing>()
                .WithCtorArg("name").EqualTo("Jeremy")
                .WithCtorArg("count").EqualTo(4)
                .WithCtorArg("average").EqualTo(.333);
        });
}
```

OR:

```
var container = new  Container(x =>
{
    x.ForConcreteType<SimplePropertyTarget>().Configure
     .SetProperty(target =>
     {
         target.Name = "Max";
         target.Age = 4;
     });
});
```

I want to do something similar...but don't know the concrete type....only the abstract class or interface (would have properties in this case).  The concrete type is configured though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer with direction from Jeremy Miller (author of StructureMap).  Here is where he pointed me to:

http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/RetrievingServices.htm#section5

here is an example of what I used:

```
IDatabaseRepository repo =
                ObjectFactory.With("server").EqualTo("servername").
                With("database").EqualTo("dbName").
                With("user").EqualTo("userName").
                With("password").EqualTo("password").
                GetInstance<IDatabaseRepository>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of [factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515269/factory-pattern-in-c-how-to-ensure-an-object-instance-can-only-be-created-by-a) to create the concrete instances.  The instant of creation *necessarily* needs to know what the concrete implementation is.

Comment: you dont need a factory pattern because StructureMap takes care of that for you.  I did find the answer though...thanks.