# Hiding the Constructors of LINQ to SQL DataContext

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using the LINQ to SQL Classes *(**DataContext**)* to connect to my DB. I have three databases with identical schema: `Development`, `Staging` and `Live`. I have realized that if they have an identical schema, I can connect to them using the same DataContext – by only changing the connection string that I pass in to the DataContext constructor. I have declared an interface so that all calls to the creation of the DataContext go through it:

```
public interface IDataContextCreator
    {
        MyDataContext CreateDataContext();
    }
```

Now I can have concerete implementations of this interface to connect to the `Development`, `Staging` or `Live` DBs.

I would now like to ***hide my DataContext constructor*** to force all calls to the creation of the **DataContext** go through the above interface. If I change the accessibility of the **DataContext** to `internal`, I cannot use it in other projects in the solution. I would ideally like to keep the class accessibility modifier as `public` but change the constructors to be `internal`. Is there any way to do this in the automatically generated classes? Is there any other solution to this problem?

Thank you.

**Edit:** 
Jon you are right the constructors should be made `internal`. I have these in my **Data Layer**, and I do not want classes in other projects/layers to get to these constructors. They however should be only able create the **DataContext** using the interface and then use the created **DataContext** - since it would be public on the class level.

Comment: Why would you want to change the constructors to *protected* rather than *internal*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671331/make-sure-object-only-created-by-factory-c

Comment: @WiktorZychla - I don't think these are duplicate because here I am concerned about the automatic generation of the **DataContext**. If I had to edit these by hand, I would simply keep the **DataContext** class as public _(i.e. to be used by everyone)_ but keep the constructors `internal`.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the VS code gen with the T4 templates at http://l2st4.codeplex.com/. With this, you could then modify the constructor code spit to be protected rather than public.

However, I have to wonder why you are using separate data contexts rather than just changing the connection information in the config files and using a transform to pull the appropriate connection string for your particular build operation. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jim. I think this is a good option. I would have preferred to set these in the properties if that was possible. I could change the connection information in the config files, but if I could do it on the fly, I could also use this in testing ;).

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your constructor as protected.

```
public class MyDataContext : DataContext {
    protected MyDataContext() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio creates the DataContext for me and I do not want to edit the autogenerated files - if there is a way out.